# Function not running on time

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, xtuple

I'm trying to create a metrics dashboard by running a nodejs application on a raspberry pi that will be attached to a large monitor.

The application queries a SQL server every hour on the hour. When I run it on my mac it works great, but when I run this on the raspberry, it seems to run once or twice, then stops. I have disabled screensavers on the raspberry but I'm not sure how to debug this. I'll include the full code since I'm not sure if it's the tick() function itself or something else...

```
"use strict";

var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
var pg = require('pg');

const config = {
    user: '<redacted>',
    database: '<redacted>',
    password: '<redacted>',
    host: '<redacted>',
    port: 5432,
    max: 10,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 5000,
};

const pool = new pg.Pool(config);

const spreadsheetId = '<this my internal sheet>'; // fulfillment kpis

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-nodejs-quickstart.json
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];
const TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
const TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'olr-test.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
    // Google Sheets API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), begin); // <---- LOOK HERE...WHERE IT REALLY BEGINS...I THINK
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
    var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
    var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
    var auth = new googleAuth();
    var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function (err, token) {
        if (err) {
            getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
        } else {
            oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
    var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function (code) {
        rl.close();
        oauth2Client.getToken(code, function (err, token) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
                return;
            }
            oauth2Client.credentials = token;
            storeToken(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
    try {
        fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
            throw err;
        }
    }
    fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
    console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

// Let's get the information out of xTuple now...
function begin(auth) {

    // Promise function to return results from SQL query passed as an argument
    function getResults(passedQuery) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            pool.connect((err, client, done) => {

                var sql = client.query(passedQuery);

                sql.on('row', (row, result) => {
                    result.addRow(row);
                });

                sql.on('end', (result) => {
                    var rightNow = timeStamp();
                    // console.log('Query finished at %s', rightNow);
                    resolve(result.rows);
                });

                done(err);

                if (err) {
                    return console.error('error running query', err);
                }
            });
        });
        pool.on('error', (err, client) => {
            console.error('idle client error', err.message, err.stack);
        });
    }

    function convertArray(sqlObj) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var result = [];

            if (sqlObj.length > 0) {
                var order = Object.keys(sqlObj[0]);

                var result = sqlObj.map((row) => {
                    return order.map((col) => {
                        return row[col];
                    });
                });   
            }

            result[0].push(timeStamp());

            resolve(result);
        });
    }

    function appendSheet (value) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var sheets = google.sheets('v4');

            var options = {
                auth: auth,
                spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
                range: "Sales ABPH!A1:B",
                valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
                resource: {
                    range: "Sales ABPH!A1:B",
                    majorDimension: "ROWS",
                    values: value,
                }
            }


            // console.log(options);
            sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(options, (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(res);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function fixFormats(id) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var sheets = google.sheets('v4');

            var options = {
                auth: auth,
                spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
                resource: {
                    requests: [{
                        repeatCell: {
                            fields: "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat",
                            range: {
                                sheetId: id,
                                startColumnIndex: 0, // inclusive
                                endColumnIndex: 1, // exclusive...meaning this counts UP TO column 4 but NOT 5
                            },
                            cell: {
                                userEnteredFormat: {
                                    numberFormat: {
                                        type: "CURRENCY",
                                        pattern: "\"$\"#,##0.00",
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }],
                }
            }

            sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(options, (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(res);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function timeStamp() {
        var now = new Date();
        var date = [now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate()];
        var time = [now.getHours(),now.getMinutes(),now.getSeconds()];
        var suffix = (time[0] < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
        time[0] = (time[0] < 12) ? time[0] : time[0] - 12;
        time[0] = time[0] || 12;

        for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            if (time[i] < 10) {
                time[i] = "0" + time[i];
            }
        }
        return date.join("/") + " " + time.join(":") + " " + suffix;
    }

    function insertRow() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var sheets = google.sheets('v4');

            var options = {
                auth: auth,
                spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
                resource: {
                    requests: [{
                        insertRange: {
                            range: {
                                sheetId: 1769404692,
                                startRowIndex: 1,
                                endRowIndex: 2,
                                startColumnIndex: 1,
                                endColumnIndex: 4
                            },
                            shiftDimension: "ROWS",
                        }
                    }],
                }
            }

            sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(options, (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(res);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function update() {
        getResults(`
        select formatMoney(sum(qry.total)) as \"Booked\"
    FROM cohead c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT coitem_cohead_id, SUM(coitem_qtyord*coitem_price) as total
        FROM coitem
        WHERE coitem_status NOT IN (\'X\')
        GROUP BY coitem_cohead_id) as qry
        ON (c.cohead_id=qry.coitem_cohead_id)
    WHERE (extract(DAY FROM c.cohead_orderdate) = extract(DAY from current_date) AND extract(MONTH from c.cohead_orderdate) = extract(MONTH from current_date) AND extract(YEAR from c.cohead_orderdate) = extract(YEAR from current_date))
        `)
            .then((sqlObj) => {
                insertRow();
                return convertArray(sqlObj);
            })
            .then((results) => {
                console.log(results);
                return appendSheet(results);
            })
            .then((fixMe) => {
                fixFormats('1769404692');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Something went wrong...\n%s', error);
            });

        tick();
    }

    function tick(force) {
        var d = new Date();
        var min = d.getMinutes();
        var sec = d.getSeconds();
        var hr = d.getHours();

        if (force || (min == '0' && sec == '0') && (hr >= 7 || hr <= 19))
            update();
        else
            setTimeout(update, (60 * (60 - min) + (60 - sec)) * 1000);    
    }

    tick(true);
}
```

I'm running it with nodemon to monitor for changes in the script file and restart if found.

My hunch is that somehow the raspberry is going into a sort of "sleep" mode but still outputs video.

EDIT: I thought I found a solution here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4773/raspberry-pi-sleep-mode-how-to-avoid/56046#56046

I've turned off power_save on for wlan0 (which is what I'm using for my LAN connection) and then rebooted. Same problem, but checking the power_save option again looks like it was turned back on.

I've just tested turn it off, rebooting, and immediately checking again it's re-enabled.

EDIT #2: Confirming that if I set power_save off on wlan0 and do not reboot, it still does not run the loop at the appropriate timeout. I waited 30 minutes before restarting it and it ran fine but that's because of the tick() is forced the first time it runs.

Comment: Your tick functions is a little complex. it's possible the issue is in the tick function. I would simply that right down. Just run the update on a interval timer and see if it works say one min. If that works then its possible the issue is with your timing and the pi clock.

Comment: If you cant debug it maybe that the code is throwing an exception when it first fetches and the tick is never recalled. Try catching exceptions in the update. Or remove all the code test that tick function works and calls update, then in update just flash the screen on the PI. That will help you narrow down where the issue lies.

Comment: Thank you I'll give that a shot. The tick function is necessary but maybe I can simplify it like you suggest. The reason the tick function is there is to run at 1:00 PM, 2:00 PM, 3:00 PM and so on. If I use setInterval as it is, and I start the script at 12:13 PM, then it doesn't run until 1:13 PM which wouldn't work for my purposes.

Comment: I was suggesting you simply for the purpose of testing/finding why you have this error. If the interval works say every 30 secs then you know its the code in your tick function.

Comment: I believe I've found the cause of this btw. I noticed everything is fine when I'm at my desk or leave my computer to stay on while the script is running. The times that it is failing or is getting offset is when my computer goes to sleep. The timeout pauses and continues when I wake the machine back up.